# very weird question for object nesting of python

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,c):
        self.c = c
    c = ""
    times = 0
    next = [None]*26
    
root = Node('x')
root.next[0] = Node('x')
print(root.next[1])
root.next[0].next[1] = Node('x')
print(root.next[1])
```

The answer:

```
None

<__main__.Node object at 0x0000018F31644670>
```

When python excute `root.next[0].next[1] = Node('x')` ，Node('x') also is written into root.next[1] . It is weird, why it happens?